# How to pass and display variable in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to learn Zend Framework 2, I already install it in my machine, I reached the welcome page, that's good, so when I look it's structure it has a big difference in CodeIgniter or Laravel, my problem is I want to display some text or string in my `index.phtml`. In my `IndexController.php` I got this.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $sample = 'sample string'; // this is what I want to pass in my index.phtml
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

1. How can I pass the variable into my `index.phtml` ?
2. How can I display it in my `index.phtml`?

For example, in CodeIgniter look like this.

```
//Controller.php
public function indexAction() {
    $data = 'Sample data'; // this is sample string that will display in my index.php
    return view('home',$data);
}
//View
<?php
   echo $data; // it will print the string in my $data(variable); 
?>
```

I'm newbie in Zend Framework 2, I don't have any idea in this framework. help me guys.
Thank you in advance for helping mo to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Zend 2, you pass any variable you want to use in your view to `ViewModel` or return an array:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $sample = 'sample string'; // this is what I want to pass in my index.phtml
    return new ViewModel(array(
        "sample" => $sample
    ));
}
```

or:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $sample = 'sample string'; // this is what I want to pass in my index.phtml
    return array(
        "sample" => $sample
    );
}
```

You can then access `$sample` in your `index.phtml` like this:

```
<?php echo $this->sample ?>
```

The array key will always be the property name of your view.

For more information see also:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Thank you for your attention.